# R - How can I check if a value in a row is different from the value in the previous row?

Tags: r, if-statement, lag

I would like to add a column to my table that compares a value with a previous value in an existing column 'farm' (to check if it is the same); and also controls if the value in the current row is "NULL". The objective is to get back in the new column 'switch' the value "new" when the value in the column 'farm' for that row is different from the value in the previous row for the column 'farm'. (exept when the value in farm is "NULL", then I would like to get back "")

See here below the desired output:

```
farm    switch
A   
A   
NULL    
B   new
B   
B   
A   new
A   
A   
B   new
B   
B   
NULL    
A   new
A
```

I tried to solve this using the below code:

```
#To add a new column switch
MyData["switch"] <- NA

#To check if the value is different from the previous row; and if the value is different from NULL
MyData$switch <- ifelse((MyData$farm == lag(MyData$farm))||MyData$farm=="NULL","",MyData$farm)
```

But when I use this code, then my added column has only empty values?
Can somebody please clarify what I am doing wrong and help me with a code that might work?

Comment: There’s no need to add a new column of `NA` values before populating it with data: The first statement is completely redundant.

Answer (score 6):

We create a logical index ('ind') by comparing the current row with the next row (we can do that by removing the 1st and last element of the 'farm' column for comparison), and also include the condition that the element is not `"NULL"`.  Based on the logical index, we can change the TRUE to 'New' and FALSE to `''` with `ifelse`.

```
ind <- with(MyData, c(FALSE, farm[-1L]!= farm[-length(farm)]) & farm!='NULL')
MyData$switch <- ifelse(ind, 'New', '')

MyData
#   farm switch
#1     A       
#2     A       
#3  NULL       
#4     B    New
#5     B       
#6     B       
#7     A    New
#8     A       
#9     A       
#10    B    New
#11    B       
#12    B       
#13 NULL       
#14    A    New
#15    A
```

To understand the concept of `[-1L]` and `-length`, suppose we have a vector

```
v1 <- c(2, 2, 3, 1, 5)
v1[-1] #removes the first observation
#[1] 2 3 1 5

v1[-length(v1)]# removes the last one
#[1] 2 2 3 1
```

When we compare these two, we are comparing the current row (`v1[-length(v1)]`) against the next row (`v1[-1]`).  As the length is one less than the original length of 'v1', we append a 'TRUE' or 'FALSE' depending upon our logical condition

```
 c(FALSE, v1[-1]!= v1[-length(v1)])
```

In your case there is a second condition that asserts the value cannot be `"NULL"`.  So when combine both of this with `&`, only the `TRUE` values in both of them get the 'TRUE' and rest are 'FALSE'.

#### data

```
MyData <- structure(list(farm = c("A", "A", "NULL", "B", "B", "B", "A", 
"A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "NULL", "A", "A")), .Names = "farm",
class =  "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Comment: Hi akrun,

Thanks for your answer. This works but I don't understand the code you are using:
farm[-1L] --> I assume this refers to the value of 'farm' on the previous row?
farm[-length(farm)]) --> What is the meaning of this operation?

Can you please also clarify which code I could use to verify if the current row is different from the NEXT row? I tried with +1L but this doesn't work..

Thanks to let me know!

Comment: @Martijn Added some explanation.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! This clarifies a lot! +1

See below a way to control if there is a difference with the next row:

`MyData$farm_new <- c(MyData$farm[-1L],MyData$farm[nrow(MyData)])`

`MyData$check <- ifelse((MyData$farm != MyData$farm_new) & (MyData$farm != "NULL"),"loss","")`

`MyData$farm_new <- NULL`

Comment: @akrun Is there any way to give this solution, a `by` argument as you would in data.table?

Comment: @akrun I made a new question for it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59073241/checking-for-a-factor-change-by-group