# Checking for a factor change by group

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table as follows:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread(
"Event_Type  country year   
A   NLD   2005
B   NLD   2004       
A   GBR   2006
B   GBR   2003   
A   GRC   2002             
A   GRC   2007",
header = TRUE)
```

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505541/r-how-can-i-check-if-a-value-in-a-row-is-different-from-the-value-in-the-previ), I know I can see if there is a change in event type as follows:

```
ind <- with(DT, c(FALSE, Event_Type  [-1L]!= Event_Type  [-length(Event_Type  )]) & Event_Type  !='NULL')
DT$switch <- ifelse(ind, 1, '')
```

But I would like to be able to do this by group as well, in this case the `country`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using data.table, you can use the `shift` function to create a lagged variable and check if event is equal to its lagged value.

```
DT[, switch := Event_Type != shift(Event_Type, fill = Event_Type[1]), country]
```

That creates the `ind` part of your code, if you want something other than TRUE/FALSE you can put it in an `ifelse` (or `fifelse` if you're on a recent data.table version).